# Loop through an asp.net button in html table <td> from code behind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want a delete button in every HTML table row in client side.How can i place an asp.net button in table cell so that i can delete a particular row from its ID.

```
        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {

            ID = row["Mem_id"].ToString();
             Name = row["Mem_Name"].ToString();
             Email = row["Mem_Email"].ToString();
             Designation = row["Mem_Designation"].ToString();
             Depart = row["Mem_Dept"].ToString();
             Phone = row["Mem_Phone"].ToString();
             MemType = row["Mem_Type"].ToString();
             image = "<img width=100 height=100 src=/imagesz/" + row["Mem_Image"].ToString() + ">";

             tbl.Text = tbl.Text + "<tr><td>" + ID + "</td><td>" + Name + "</td><td>" + Email + "</td><td>" + Designation + "</td><td>" + Depart + "</td><td>" + Phone + "</td><td>" + MemType + "</td><td>" + image + "</td><td>I WANT TO ADD ASP.NET DELETE BUTTON HERE</td></tr>";


        }


    }
```

Comment: What is tbl?  What do you mean by "delete a particular row from its ID"?

Comment: tbl.text is actually a asp.net label. and  i want delete button in table cell so that i can delete any row from table records.

Comment: uh, how did you create the table? is it by string concatenation? if so, its a bad idea.. try your luck with [`Repeater`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: yes i know ! thank you for your answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a server-side control (such as an ASP:Button) by putting it into the markup. There is much more to a control than its HTML.

To add buttons for each row, I suggest you abandon your approach of constructing an HTML string, and instead use either a [Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094401/buttons-and-repeater-control) or a [GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486062/how-do-i-add-a-column-with-buttons-in-to-a-gridview-in-asp-net). If you follow the links it'll show you how to add a button to each.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please more context? I think is a bit confusing trying to help with an approach. So far, John Wu Has provided a good answer. This can be address by using asp controls.